# scroll function triggering before reaching end point?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onscroll, onscrolllistener

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import Home from './Components/Home/Home';
import Explainers from './Components/Explainers/Explainers';
import VideoCreation from './Components/VideoCreation/VideoCreation';
import Video from './Components/Video/Video';
import Footer from './Components/Footer/Footer';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {isExplainers:false, isVideoExp:false }
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }
   componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }
   componentWillUnMount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll=()=>{
    console.log("scroll handle")
    this.setState({isExplainers:true});
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.videoScroll);
  }
  videoScroll = () =>{
    console.log("scroll of Video");
    this.setState({isVideoExp:true});
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.ourVideoScroll);
  }
  ourVideoScroll=()=>{
    console.log("our Video Scroll");
  }
  render() {
    const explainersClass = this.state.isExplainers ? "explainerAfter" : "explainer";
     const creationClass = this.state.isVideoExp ? "videoCreationAfter" : "videoCreation";
     const ourVideoClass = this.state.isExplainers ? "videoCreationAfter" : "videoCreation";
    return (

      <div className="App">
      <Home  onScroll = {this.handleScroll}/>
      <div className={explainersClass} onScroll={this.videoScroll}><Explainers /></div>
      <div className={creationClass} onScroll={this.ourVideoScroll}><VideoCreation /></div>
      <div className={ ourVideoClass } > <Video /></div>
      <Footer /> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In this i have three onScroll functions where i need a functionality of working one after the other should update once it reaches the end of the component all are getting updated at once any wrong in my code ? or any other forms or methods for doing this using other frameworks or else ?

Answer (score 1):

You need not add scroll event for each function, rather you can just call it from the previous function. Also since setState is async, you would call these function from the setState callback which is executed after setState is completed

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {isExplainers:false, isVideoExp:false }
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }
   componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }
   componentWillUnMount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll=(e)=>{
    console.log("scroll handle");
    const explainer = React.findDOMNode(this.explainer);
    const home = React.findDOMNode(this.home);
    if(home.scrollTop === explainer.offsetTop) { 
       this.setState({ isExplainers : true });
    }
  }
  videoScroll = () => {
    const explainer = React.findDOMNode(this.explainer);
    const video = React.findDOMNode(this.video);
    if(explainer.scrollTop === video.offsetTop) { 
       this.setState({ isVideoExp : true });
    }
  }
  ourVideoScroll=()=>{
    console.log("our Video Scroll");
    const ourVideo = React.findDOMNode(this.ourVideo);
    const video = React.findDOMNode(this.video);
    if(video.scrollTop === ourVideo.offsetTop) { 
       // take action here
    }
  }
  render() {
    const explainersClass = this.state.isExplainers ? "explainerAfter" : "explainer";
     const creationClass = this.state.isVideoExp ? "videoCreationAfter" : "videoCreation";
     const ourVideoClass = this.state.isExplainers ? "videoCreationAfter" : "videoCreation";
    return (

      <div className="App">
      <Home  ref={ref => this.home = ref} onScroll = {this.handleScroll}/>
      <div className={explainersClass} ref={ref => this.explainer = ref} onScroll={this.videoScroll}><Explainers /></div>
      <div className={creationClass} ref={ref => this.video = ref} onScroll={this.ourVideoScroll}><VideoCreation /></div>
      <div className={ ourVideoClass } ref={ref => this.ourVideo = ref}> <Video /></div>
      <Footer /> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: let me try this

Comment: it gets executed immediately before reaching the end of the component or even the starting of it

Comment: What is the expected behaviour, Also why did you have onScoll on all the 3 divs, If its a currying functionality you may as well have it only once, If you want it to be executed when the scroll reaches the component end, you may need to compare the scrollPosition with the component offset + height

Comment: the functionality i am looking is if the scroll once reaches the explainer class then it should update the next state which i wrote in the function but this all are triggered if i put one function in the other

Comment: now only the first function is being other two are not called